# NuGet packages and the bin folder in ASP.NET Web Pages site

Tags: asp.net, nuget

This is probably a very basic question but **what's the mechanism for DLLs under the `packages` folder to get copied into the `bin` folder?**

As an example, I have a solution that contains a single "project" (node) of type Web Site (i.e., no `csproj`, just file-system-based). It is a very basic static website. I want to add ASP.NET Web Pages support so I install [this NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages/) and now there are some DLLs under the `packages` folder and my `web.config` has been updated. However, when I run the site, it shows YSOD with the error "Could not determine which version of ASP.NET Web Pages to use" which I guess is because there is no `bin` folder with DLLs in it (when I create a "Razor" site from scratch in Visual Studio, the `bin` folder is there). If I try to rebuild the solution, it fails with the same error which is compilation error (not runtime error) this time.

What's the command or mechanism to restore the `bin` folder from the `packages` folder? I don't want to have DLLs in my source control and according to NuGet docs, it seems that this workflow is very much supported. I guess that if it were csproj-based project, there would be some MS Build action or something like that to use the DLLs from the `packages` folder but this is a website and I cannot define advanced build actions, can I?

Comment: That package is already installed when I create a new ASP.NET Web Site(Razor v3).

Comment: Yeah, it is when you start from scratch. But see the example in the question - I am starting from an already existing project that has no `bin` folder, currently.

Comment: _I don't want to have DLLs in my source control and according to NuGet docs, it seems that this workflow is very much supported._ This is supported when you can build a project. NuGet package restore downloads the required packages before the build. You will have to create a bin folder and commit it to source control I think.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using Visual Studio 2013, when I install a NuGet package, such as Microsoft.AspNet.Razor, into an ASP.NET web pages application then the bin folder is created.

Getting the binaries into the bin folder is part of the build process and it is not done by NuGet. NuGet can be used to restore the files into the packages folder but will not do anything with your bin folder when restoring.

For building and package restore to work it looks like you need to keep the bin folder and any .refresh files. You can remove the other binaries from your version control system.

```
System.Web.Razor.dll.refresh
```

The contents of this file tells Visual Studio where to find the NuGet packages:

```
 ..\..\Projects\MyWebSite\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.1.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.dll
```

To test this, I deleted all the binaries from the bin folder, removed the packages folder, and then rebuilt the project. Visual Studio restores the packages and when building copies the required assemblies to the project's bin folder.

Comment: Good pointer to the `refresh` files! Unfortunately, VS 2013 doesn't seem to have a way to Add Reference to a DLL somewhere inside the `packages` folder but at least I can copy those *.refresh files from some temporary project and start from there. Don't you know, will Azure Web Sites understand the *.refresh files? It's my target hosting environment.

Comment: The *.dll.refresh files are understood by MSBuild. They are used by Web Site projects since these do not have any project file (.csproj) to put the assembly references. As part of the deployment something will need to do a NuGet restore, then MSBuild will need to be run to copy the binaries across, before the site is published. All of this will be supported by Visual Studio. So it should be OK if you are deploying to Azure using Visual Studio. Deploying the site without using Visual Studio is another question.